# Could not generate timestamp: Connection reset

Tags: air

I get the following error when compiling an adobe air application:

```
 [java] Could not generate timestamp: Connection reset
```

This application previously compiled fine a few days earlier.  I don't know of any configuration changes to the computer.

Answer (score 4):

I added the following arguments to the build.xml file and the error went away:

```
  <arg value="-tsa" />
  <arg value="http://sha256timestamp.ws.symantec.com/sha256/timestamp" />
```

My guess is that symantec moved the timestamp service that air is using.

[EDIT]
We do builds from the command line using ant; ant uses a file called build.xml.  If you are running the adt command from the command line or from a .bat script then you would add `-tsa http://sha256timestamp.ws.symantec.com/sha256/timestamp` to the existing command.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Really helped me resurrect an old AIR application :)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue when trying to sign an application with multiple certificates when doing a certificate renewal.

Based on Michael Potter's answer, if you are trying to use ADT to multi-sign the certificate you can use the following command:

```
adt -migrate -tsa "http://sha256timestamp.ws.symantec.com/sha256/timestamp" -storetype pkcs12 -keystore old_cert.p12 myAppIn.air myAppOut.air
```

- old_cert.p12 - the path to the certificate you want to add (this
  would be the old certificate which is now expired)
- MyAppIn.air - the app signed with the new certificate
- MyAppOut.air - the new file to be created when this process is
  complete

Answer (score 1):

To fix my build.xml I added:

```
<arg line="-tsa http://sha256timestamp.ws.symantec.com/sha256/timestamp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before, lets say 6 months, similar issue was happening: "Handshake error"

It was due to Java 1.6 being used. Now, I did the same, just other timestamp URL:

```
<arg value="-tsa http://timestamp.digicert.com" />
```