# Failing to compile Flex desktop apps in Flash Builder 4.7

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

All of a sudden the compilation of all desktop apps fails in Flash Builder 4.7 with the following message: "Could not generate timestamp: Remote host closed connection during handshake".

In October 2016 this problem appeared for the first time, back then I was able to solve the problem with this information: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2218793

Since then I haven't changed anything in my Java configuration. However, it seems that recently the timestamp service has moved: [Could not generate timestamp: Connection reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43555116/could-not-generate-timestamp-connection-reset)

My question is: how do I set up properly this timestamp service configuration in Flash Builder 4.7 in order to compile desktop apps with the "Export Release Build" function?

Answer (score 0):

See this thread on the Adobe Air Development forum:

https://forums.adobe.com/message/9482291#9482291

Also, I think that I saw a message indicating that the default server has been changed in the latest build of the AIR 26 beta, which should fix this.

Comment: Hey Douglas! (Roy)